# Craft 3 multisite: site specific config

Tags: craft3, config, multi-site

I'm trying to do something like this in general.php config for a multi-site setup:

```
// ...
'production' => array(
    'myVariable' => array(
        'site1Handle' => '111',
        'site2Handle' => '222',
    ),
),
// ...
```

So, when we do:

```
{{ craft.app.config.general.myVariable }}
```

We can get different values ("111" or "222") based on which site I'm on.

I believe that we can do something similar to this in Craft 2 (was multi-lingual though). See https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/localization-guide.html#step-4-define-your-site-urls

Can we still do this in Craft 3?

Comment: How about `{{ craft.app.config.general.myVariable[currentSite.handle] }}`?

Comment: @DedNolyxeux good solution. Thanks Ded!